# In flutter, how to parse Excel file to JSON and get "keys" in result?

Tags: json, excel, flutter

I want to parse Excel file to JSON file and get result like this structors:

```
{
   "1": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "00000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    },
    "2": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "000000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    },
    "3": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "000000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    },
    "4": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "000000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    },
    "5": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "0000000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    },
    "6": {
        "Student Name": "Student Name",
        "Phone Number": "000000000",
        "Status": "OK"
    }
}

This function parse Excel file to JSON without the "keys" I wanted.

    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> parseExcelToJSON(String filePath) async {
  
  var bytes = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();
  var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

  // Assuming the first sheet is the one you want to parse
  var sheet = excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first]; // Before user choose sheet

  var rows = sheet!.rows; // Before user choose sheet
  // var rows = sheet.rows;  // user choose sheet
  var headerRow = rows.first;
  var dataRows = rows.sublist(1); // Exclude the header row

  var jsonData = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

  for (var row in dataRows) {
    var rowData = <String, dynamic>{};
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      var header = headerRow[i]!.value.toString();
      
      var value = row[i]?.value.toString() ?? '';

      rowData[header] = value;
    }
    jsonData.add(rowData);
  }

  return jsonData;
}
```

A few word about the JSON file I provided:

1. The JSON data consists of an object where each key represents a student ID (e.g., "1", "2", etc.), and the corresponding value is an object containing information about that student.
2. Each student object contains the following key-value pairs:

   "Student Name": The name of the student.
   "Phone Number": The phone number of the student.
   "Status": The status of the student, which is marked as "OK" in each case.

**How to achive this?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `excel` package
`https://pub.dev/packages/excel`

```
    var bytes = File(file).readAsBytesSync();
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      print(table); //sheet Name
      print(excel.tables[table].maxCols);
      print(excel.tables[table].maxRows);
      for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
        print('$row');
      }
    }


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/excel
```

Comment: Can you provide me the full code please without the UI?

Comment: share me your mail code is lengthy. platform didn't allowing me to share this long code here

Comment: This is the function that parse the Excel file to JSON. But I did not get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

We use this tool.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:spreadsheet_decoder/spreadsheet_decoder.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  if (args.isEmpty || args.length > 2) {
    print('Usage:');
    print('xls2json  input.xls [output.json]');
    exit(-1);
  }

  final inputFile = args[0];
  final outputFile = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '$inputFile.json';
  final inputBytes = File(inputFile).readAsBytesSync();
  final inputExcel = SpreadsheetDecoder.decodeBytes(inputBytes, update: true);
  final sheets = <Object>[];
  for (final excelSheet in inputExcel.tables.values) {
    final rows = <Object?>[];
    for (final excelRow in excelSheet.rows) {
      final row = <Object?>[];
      rows.add(row);
      for (var excelCell in excelRow) {
        if (excelCell is num) {
          final intValue = excelCell.round();
          if (excelCell == intValue) {
            excelCell = intValue;
          }
        }

        if (excelCell != null) {
          row.add('$excelCell');
        } else {
          row.add('');
        }
      }
    }

    final sheet = {
      'name': excelSheet.name,
      'rows': rows,
    };

    sheets.add(sheet);
  }

  final contents = jsonEncode({
    'sheets': sheets,
  });
  File(outputFile).writeAsStringSync(contents);
}
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "name": "Sheet1",
      "rows": [
        [
          "Hello, Table is below.",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "Id",
          "date"
        ],
        [
          "1",
          "2023-01-20T00:00:00.000"
        ],
        [
          "2",
          "2023-01-20T00:00:00.000"
        ],
        [
          "5",
          "2023-01-20T00:00:00.000"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Other",
      "rows": [
        [
          "Other sheet"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]